# Some characters not rendering in code blocks

Tags: bug, mobile-web, fonts

I have noticed on the mobile site that many characters do not render in code blocks. For example:

**In a code block:**

[image]

**Copied out of a code block:**

[image]

[**From here**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/phonemic-abugida)

Comment: On my Win10 box with Chrome I can't repro this. Does this mean it depends on your OS an the installed fonts?

Comment: @rene: Yes. And in some cases also on the browser and its configuration. In any case, it's not something SE can really fix. You just need to install a monospace font that has those characters, and get your browser to use it.